# How private networks enable external networks in multiple network interfaces

Tags: networking, linux-networking, port-forwarding, rocky-linux

In a dual LAN environment on the Rocky Linux OS, we've made one private network from two multi-interfaces. I want to implement the private network so that it can be connected to the Internet network by taking a signal from eth1 to the gateway.
how to do that

Please Check the IMG ↓

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxnJq.png)

*I want to implement Linux like a router.*